# Is it possible to animate the path in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, fabricjs

We can use paths in fabric.js in the following way:

```
let path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 100 100 Z', {});

canvas.add(path);
```

Or we could animate them by some property like opacity:

```
path.animate('opacity', 1, {
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
});
```

Is there any way to animate the joining of each point of the path? In this case, is it possible to see the path going from (0, 0) to (100, 100). This is a silly example and I could easily achieve this result by using something other than paths but I wanted to know if I could do it this way to animate more complicated stuff with paths.

Answer (score 0):

no you would have to do the animation your self and update the path data over an interval of time.